# what happens if I ignore "coding nicely" and put css(using style tag) and js(using script tag) code in one html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For about page, I'm just using a template from http://html5up.net/license for two reasons. One;there won't be many people checking my about page any way. two; I would rather spend my time on different thing and use free template.

Because I'm using the code I didn't write for this, I want this to be seperated. I don't want this to be interfere with my css and javascript folder. So, I added long css and javascript code in one html file. readability of code can't be worse than this, but it's just about page that I won't change frequently.

My question is if I add all of them in one html page, will it be a problem to my website's functionality?

Comment: _"My question is if I add all of them in one html page, will it be a problem to my website's functionality?"_ No.

Comment: @guest271314 well said sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if I add all of them in one html page, will it be a
>   problem to my website's functionality?

No.The effective result would be a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Comment: so just readability hurts eh?no problem with security, efficiency of the web?

Comment: @emfour There should not be any issues with security or efficiency.  Given you would be the sole maintainer; only you would be affected by the readability of the `html`, `css`, `js` . The machine that reads and renders the text is concerned with the syntax of the language. See also Single page apps in depth http://singlepageappbook.com/single-page.html

Answer (score 4):

It's actually recommended by some people to include all Javascript and CSS embedded in the page, even if it's repeated across many pages on the website.

The reason for that is because it reduces the number of HTTP requests to the server and makes you website's load-time *much* faster, especially when a user hits your website from a Google search result (one-time users). For web portals, it is *not* recommended because the user will continually browse through pages, and the Javascript/CSS is expected to be cached in a separate file.

Here's an example of how much slower a webpage can be with multiple external Javascript/CSS pointers:

[image: Overhead Chart]

If all those files were embedded into the page, the load time will decrease. Only after loading many pages on the same site will the repeated code will start to take effect.

Comment: oh, I didnt know this. so it actually makes the web load faster hmmm interesting

Comment: Just a quick note: This tends to be a recommendation targetted at single page apps, rather than advice to be followed blindly. This is because single page apps will load the page just once, so it becomes more efficient to include everything you need to display the initial view in that one page. This benefit is removed if your site has a lot of different pages.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding your code to an external stylesheet / script and linking that stylesheet & script in your document. eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about-page.css">

<script src="about-page.js"></script>
```

This way you avoid messy code, and some common pitfalls that come with inline CSS / JS.

Or you can add to the existing CSS / JS files and add comments organizing your code, indicating what you added, etc...

There shouldn't be any huge problem, with exception of not being easily managed, but you really need to understand the `'cascade`' in `'Cascading Style Sheets'` to see what potential problems may arise.

It's important to remember that anything declared inline in your file holds more weight than things defined in an external stylesheet. So if `a {text-decoration: none;}` is defined in your external stylesheet, and you define `a {text-decoration: underline;}` in your html document. Your links will now be underlined, due to specificity.

To learn more about how the `'Cascading'` aspect of CSS see Mozilla Developer Network - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but I already acknowledge cascading and specificity. like I explained above, I don't want external(code I didn't write) to be in more than one file(html) in my project. I would like to know what you mean by "potential problems may arise." do you mean just readability? if the problem is security or speed I would use cscading for this but if it's just for readability I'm sticking in one html file

Comment: The potential problems I am referring to are due to the cascade / specificity. It is all to easy to overwrite rules / declarations, and even more difficult to debug, if errors from overriding do come up. Speed or security are negligible, I doubt you'll notice any problem in those areas. The main is just overwriting something you may not mean to overwrite, and trouble debugging due to cluttered code. But best of luck, and sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: If it weren't for physics and law enforcement, I'd be unstoppable.

Answer (score 2):

Well sometimes using JavaScript or other bad practices to get an output that is "functional" my affect your SEO score which is used by search engines to recommend your page to users who might be searching for something you have.

Apart from this you will not be able to use technologies like gzip compression which greatly affect page load speed.

you might want to check:

**[Why page insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)**

**[gzip compression and caching](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)**

**[Website vs Web application](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjskOjHpNjLAhVGVRQKHRcgApcQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8694922%2Fwhats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application&usg=AFQjCNHjETID7fNFWC0Q0iys7g3JySrnwQ&sig2=g8JK4fDbm9mmcc2sOTMHWg)**

So simply a website is not only about functionality, it is about reach-ability, usability, and recommendation by search engines.